# Can't extract the result from an async function, even if it's displayed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to use the ID returned by a mongoDB `insertOne` to use it in another function.

```
const saveProjectonDB = async function(Projet) {
    var projectadded
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const db = client.db(dbName)
        projectadded = await db.collection('Projets').insertOne(Projet)
        projectadded = projectadded.ops[0]._id

        client.close();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    return projectadded;
}

module.exports.saveProjectonDB = saveProjectonDB
```

When I call this function, I use this code :

```
Projet.prototype.saveProject = async function() {
    let result = await OPonDB.saveProjectonDB(this)
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

`console.log` displays the ID, it's perfect. BUT I can't use it : if I call my function, in server.js :

```
let test = projet1.saveProject();
console.log(test)
```

The result is `Promise ( <pending> )`

I don't understand why : the ID has been displayed, so it exists !
+ I would like to add the "ID" in the `Projet` object to use it later, but `this._id = result` or others tries like this one doesn't have any effect...

Thanks for you help, I'm helpless on this one...

Comment: You have to `await projet1.saveProject()` (or use saveProject().then()), just like you did `await db.collection`. See [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an async function, you must await it.

You can do this in two ways:

1. `let test = await projet1.saveProject();
   console.log(test)`
2. `projet1.saveProject().then(test => { console.log(test); })`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did that earlier, and it works, but it's not what I want to do : I still can't use the result. I can display the result in the console, but I can't get it in a var and use it somewhere else, outside an async scope ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: You code works, it displays the result in the console. But, outside the code line you wrote (the second one), test doesn't contain anything except "Promise <pending>"

Comment: and if I make a quick async function to use await, as soon as I leave the async function, the result is still a "Promise <pending>", even if it was OK inside the async function

Comment: Seems like there is some sort of double promise, try to await ``test``. If that resolves successfully you should look into your code and get that sorted.

Comment: `test.then(function(result) { console.log(result) })` shows the ID in the console, while `test2 = test.then(function(result) { console.log(result) })` doesn't put the ID in `test2`... same behaviour if I replace `test2` with `test` and `test` with my function (I am in the `server.js` file, outside any function or block)

Comment: Assigning a variable to a promise that you resolve, will not return the value.

Comment: So, the code that defines `Projet.prototype.saveProject` is not supposed to work ? well, the value seems to be in the `result` variable, but only when inside the scope of the async function. The async function doesn't really return the value of the ID, it only handles it inside the function

Comment: by using ```.then``` you are waiting for the ``resolve`` callback to be fired. Looks like the ``result`` in your ``saveProject`` function is not resolved.

Comment: I didn't use `.then` at first, I just tried when you kindly answered me. The problem is still the same as in my original post : when inside the async saveProject, `var result = await OPonDB.saveProjectonDB(this)` works fine, I can even console.log it, and when I try to `return` my result, it's a promise again.

Comment: Please try this

``Projet.prototype.saveProject = async function() {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
        let result = await OPonDB.saveProjectonDB(this)
        console.log(result)
        resolve(result);
    })
}``

and then

``let test = await projet1.saveProject();
console.log(test)``

Comment: Thanks for trying, still the same problem. As soon as I want to console.log any var supposed to store the ID outside the scope of an async function, it keeps saying `Promise <pending>`

Comment: Well I think I will give up. I've spent too much hours on this sh*t, I will erase this code that obviously doesn't work and think about another way to do what I want to do. Thanks very much for trying dude, I appreciate

Comment: in saveProject or when u await it?

Comment: If you will send me the full project i will be happy to try and help you.

Comment: That's very kind, maybe we could discuss via Telegram, so I can show you the full project ?

Comment: I do not have telegram, but i do have discord. If you do please add me testusertohelp123#7660

Answer (score 0):

you need to add await `async` function always returns`Promise`

you need to use await in order to get the value

so your code should be like `let test = await projet1.saveProject();`

Comment: So there's no way to make the result available outside an async function ? For example, projet1 is an object I created in the global scope of server.js, well I can't add the ID from projet1.saveProject() anywhere ? Like, in the var projet1.foo ?

Comment: actually using await will let you access the ID from anywhere,
actually, after adding await, the variable `test `   will get the ID value normally.
maybe you need to declare a new function `getter ` which its job is calling your main function and assign the result to a global one

Comment: `projet1.saveProject().then(function(result) { console.log(result) })` shows the ID in the console, while `test = projet1.saveProject().then(function(result) { return result })` doesn't put the ID in `test`... I feel like I'm losing my mind ^^

Comment: yes this is a little weird, use await instead of playing with ` promise chain ` will make your code cleaner

Comment: Sure, that's why I wrote async functions for the first time yesterday, and I've been trying for like 10 hours on this problem, still don't get why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Hobey823 solved my issue...

The only reason why I didn't see the modifications in my Object projet1 is because of a timing issue.

```
Projet.prototype.saveProject = async function() {
    var result = await OPonDB.saveProjectonDB(this)
    this._id = result;
    console.log(result)
    return result;
}
```

This code actually works, I can see it with a timeOut:

`setTimeout(() => console.log(projet1), 5000)`